# How to reference static resources from another web project with Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, static

How to reference static resources from another web project with Spring MVC 4. We have 2 projects one with conext root /SampleWeb and other with /SampleStatic. Sample web project is a Spring MVC 4 application that needs to access the static HTML pages from /SampleStatic project.

We tried with the below configurations for MVC resource handler but it does not work. The code is in /SampleWeb AppConfig.java file

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/views/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/SampleStatic/");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few alternatives. First note that your configuration is based on the Spring's [Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader) abstraction

in Spring MVC the prefix inside the location instructs the lookup strategy, and there are four types

```
classpath: - resources loaded from the classpath.
file: - resources loaded as a URL, from the filesystem.
http: - resources loaded as a URL.
(none) - depends on the underlying `ApplicationContext`
```

Your current config is the forth strategy. If its not working, than check how you loaded the [context](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx) to learn whether the path will be relative to classpath or the relative path based on the context file system location.

My advice to you, since you're mixing the two apps, is to find the least common denominator `classpath`, `file` or `http` and use the prefix explicitely

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me : registry.addResourceHandler("/views/**").addResourceLocations(
            "http://localhost:9080/SampleStatic/views/");